# Laravel database migration failed using laradock

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

I am getting the following error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = testdb and table_name = migrations)
```

when i run -

```
php artisan migrate
```

I am running this command on laradock workspace. I entered the workspace using the following command.

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

I am using laravel 5.5. I have laradock inside my project folder in following way.

```
 +testproject
              -Laradock
```

My project .env (testproject/.env) file contains the following settings for mysql.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

My laradock .env(testproject/laradock/.env) file contains the following settings for mysql.

```
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=33060
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

My docker-compose.yml contains the following settings for Mysql Container

```
mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE={MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER={MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD={MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend
```

Mysql in docker is installed in port 33060. I am trying laradock for the first time. After trying several configurations now i am calling out for Avengers !!!

Comment: How did you start your containers?

Comment: Did you launch your mysql container `docker-compose up -d mysql` ?

Comment: yes .. mysql container is running .. @veNuker

Comment: Try to connect and login to myslq `docker-compose exec mysql bash` + `mysql -u root -p` and check if yout database exists.

Comment: a database named "testdb" exists in server. @veNuker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem by having the following mysql settings.

testproject/.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

testproject/laradock/.env:

```
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=33060
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

testproject/laradock/docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend
```

I also ran the following two commands in laradock folder

```
docker-compose down

docker-compose up -d mysql
```

Comment: Well done :) So it was a database access issue after all?

Comment: Thank you. The key point here being that the 3306 port number remains the same within the internal laradock network, and you custom 33060 port number is only relevant when the mysql container is exposed to the host machine. Internally it still uses 3306, so that's the port your laravel app needs to use as it is running internally within laradock.